# EfficientDet Low Accuracy

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api, faster-rcnn, efficientnet

I use TensorFlow 2.3 and tested all EfficientDet models. It is written on the TensorFlow github [page](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md) that EfficientDet D7 has higher mAP than NasNet as 51.5 > 43 [Tf1_models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf1_detection_zoo.md). But in testing data, I can see that EfficientDet has really lower accuracy then other models. Why NasNet is much more accurate than EfficientDet while it has lower mAP?
Here results can be seen:
Nas detection:
[image]

Efficient detection:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The first place to check is whether you have done all the input preprocessing steps for respective model incase you are using COCO or PASCAL VOC pretrained model. If you are doing custom training there are many a ways a model can do wrong. Kindly check this out https://karpathy.github.io/2019/04/25/recipe/ .